# Chain rule of partial derivative wrt implicit variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm supposed to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ of $f(x,y,z) = \frac{2yz}{x}$ using the chain rule where $x, y, z$ are given functions of $t$.  But I'm wondering if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is even defined since $f$ is not explicitly a function of $t$.  I know that we could do the chain rule with the *total* derivative of $f$, but I'm just not sure

1. that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is meaningful and
2. how to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$.  Assuming it is meaningful would it just be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \sum\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Define the function $\phi(t) = f(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ and take the derivative. 1. is abuse of notation in my mind, and, given the abuse, 2. is correct.

Comment: So in this case $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{df}{dt}$?  Thanks.

Comment: I think that without extra context it is a notational morass. You need to follow your teacher's lead on this...